# Does anyone know how to capture Raw Soap Response in .Net without SoapExtensions

Tags: web-services, soap

Does anyone know another way to access the raw Soap Response in .Net when using a proxy class to call a Soap WebService other than using to SoapExtensions? The SoapExtensions is no good to me since I can only pass constant data to it in the method attribute constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Method A - Fake SoapHeader
(1) Construct an abstract class derived from SoapHeader.
(2) Allow the client to derived a class from (1).
(3) Apply the abstract class as a SoapHeader in the [client | service]
(4) SoapExtension reads the Soap message in the following manner.
a) When message is [SoapClientMessage | SoapServerMessage] and BeforeSerialize
i) Read the message.Headers and locate the abstract type in the SoapHeaderCollection.
ii) Set a private member variable in the SoapExtension as the instance of the 'this' header.
iii) Remove the header from the the SoapHeaderCollection to prevent serialization.

Method B - Alter Method Signature
(1) Alter the method signature of the WebMethod to include one or more parameters encoded with [XmlIgnore]
a) If method is on the client, then [XmlIgnore] parameters are 'IN' parameters.
b) If the method is on the server, then [XmlIgnore] parameters are 'OUT' parameters.
(2) Alter the method.Invoke in the implementation code of the method to include this newly added parameters on the client.
(3) SoapExtension read the Soap message in the following manner.
a) When message is SoapClientMessage and BeforeSerialize
i) Retrieve the InParameterValues from the message that are associated with the [XmlIgnore] and set private member variables in the SoapExtension for each [XmlIgnore] parameter.
b) When message is SoapServerMessage and BeforeSerialize
i) Retrieve the OutParameterValues from the message that are associated with the [XmlIgnore] and set private member variales in the SoapExtension for each [XmlIgnore] parameter.